# Error With South When Running Unit Tests Using Nose

Tags: django, migration, nose, django-south

I'm having some difficulty getting my django tests to run properly; I'm using nose, and I started getting an error when the migrations were being applied, that from table 1 a foreign key relation to table 2 failed with the error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation "table2_column" does not exist
```

Looking at the way the migrations were being applied it was clear to me that table1 was not created prior to the foreign key relation was applied, so I tried to figure out how to force the dependency, and found the following article:
http://south.aeracode.org/docs/dependencies.html

I then added:

```
depends_on = (
    ("app2", "0001_inital"),
)
```

to my app1/0001_initial.py file.

Unfortunately now I'm getting the following error:

```
south.exceptions.DependsOnUnknownMigrationMigration 'app1:0001_initial' depends on unknown migration 'app2:0001_inital'.
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Not sure if I can help much, but now I discovered nose! I already knew about south, but had rolled my own testing framework since I didn't know about nose. For the south error, does the file exist at /app2/migrations/0001_initial.py?

Comment: Yes, the migration does indeed exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo in the name of the migration it's depending on. It should be:

```
depends_on = (
    ("app2", "0001_initial"),
)
```

This dependency system worked for me, after having exactly the same issue you list here, and then finding the dependency system South's docs.

Comment: I actually haven't tested this since I subsequently worked around this, but I definitely had a typo there!

Answer (score 19):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but you can add a setting to use syncdb instead of migrations when running tests. Add the following line to your settings.py

```
SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False
```

Comment: THANKS! this helped a ton. I'm tempted to select this as the answer, but would really like to know if I could get the migrations to work.

Answer (score 0):

This error is also thrown if there is an error during the import of the target module: If you've got hand-constructed migrations and you're certain the file name matches your **depends_on** or **needed_by**, check the referenced file for errors.

Also, setting SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE to False won't fix the problem. It just means you won't see the problem until you try to use the migration.

http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html

(That's still useful if you want to speed up your unittests.)